# Inline Keyboard text changing

Tags: python, aiogram

My task is to create small bot which is a product list. When user sends products, it answers with the Inline keyboard and buttons, each single button is one of the products(initially there are red cross next to the text) When user press a button, it must change cross to a green check mark(name of product must stay).
How to implement it?

code that creates a list:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def show_list(message: types.Message):
    productlist = message.text.split(',')
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for product in productlist:
        keyboard.row(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'❌ {product}', callback_data=f'{product}'))
    await message.answer("Список продуктов: ", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

[that's how it works in telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SATVn.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to do this task.

Step one: Define a variable to record the selected products.

Step two: Define a `callback query handler` to access the callbacks.

```py
selected_products = {}


@dp.message_handler()
async def show_list(message: types.Message):
    global selected_products; selected_products[message.message_id] = []

    productlist = message.text.split(',')
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for product in productlist:
        keyboard.row(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'❌ {product}', callback_data=f'{product}'))
    await message.answer("Список продуктов: ", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def update_productlist(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global selected_products

    if call.message.message_id - 1 in selected_products.keys():
        selected_products[call.message.message_id - 1].append(call.data)
    else:
        return 1

    productlist = []

    keyboard = call.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard
    for row in keyboard:
        for col in row:
            productlist.append(col.callback_data)

    new_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    for product in productlist:
        if product in selected_products[call.message.message_id - 1]:
            new_keyboard.row(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'✔️ {product}', callback_data=f'{product}'))
        else:
            new_keyboard.row(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'❌ {product}', callback_data=f'{product}'))
    else:
        await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup=new_keyboard)
```

Note: This way has a bug. If the user enters another command before the product list response, the returned product list will not be interactive.

Comment: thank you very much! that was very useful. what sources can you recommend for learning aiogram?

Comment: Actually, I didn't learn this library seriously. But for this case, I took help from the source document of this library (https://docs.aiogram.dev).
And a bit of Telegram documentation for better understanding (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).